# PL/SQL - Trigger when inserting row containing some value

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a question concerning triggers in PL/SQL:

I want to make a trigger that runs when I insert a row onto a specific table; this row must have a certain value (4 in this case) under a certain column ("idstage" in this case).

**For example:** if i add a row with an idstage column value of 3 onto table01, my trigger should not fire. But, if I add a row with an idstage column value of 4, my trigger should fire.

I read the documentation but I am a bit confused on the specifics for using triggers in PL/SQL. I got some tips on when to use "table level triggers" and "row level triggers" from this article: [Before, after, each row and table level triggers [Oracle]](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/trigger/before_after_each_row.html)

---

So far I have something like this:

```
create or replace trigger bb_ordcancel_trg
  after insert on table01
  when (idstage = 4)

  declare
    /* body declarations */
  begin
    /* body */
  end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the requirement.  If you are trying to ensure that a particular column has a particular value, you'd really want to use a `check` constraint not a trigger.

Comment: @JustinCave I edited in an example to my question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'table level triggers' ? Maybe do you mean `statement level triggers` ? Both `row level` and `statement level` are fired for tables, so we can say that both are "table level triggers".

Comment: create or replace trigger vish_test
  after insert on tst
  for each row
  when (new.t1 = 4)
begin
  insert into vish_test values (:new.t1);
end;

Comment: Well I figured it out but since you guys marked it as duplicate I cannot answer it... it would be: create or replace trigger bb_ordcancel_trg after insert on table01 for each row when (NEW.idstage = 4) /*body*/  ..I guess I didn't ask my question clearly enough.